# If $f$ is holomorphic on some open set $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is infinitely often complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $G$. Let $a\in G$ be arbitrary. The reason why $f$ is infinitely often complex differentiable is, in my opinion (if I'm wrong, please tell me), based on Cauchy's Integral Formula for Derivatives,

> If $\overline{B(a,r)}\subseteq G$, then for every $z_0\in B(a,r)$ we have
> $$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z,\quad n=0,1,2,\dots
> $$

Clearly, one can find $\rho>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subseteq G$, because $G$ is open. But, is the existence of $\rho'>0$ satisfying that $\overline{B(a,\rho')}\subseteq G$ guaranteed?

Comment: $\overline{B(a,r/2)}\subset B(a, r) \subset G$.

Comment: @MartinR That's nice. So, the radius $r$ depends on the choice of $a$ (right?), and then create a small closed ball inside this open ball, say $\rho':=r/2$. The theorem in OP tells us that $f$ is infinitely often differentiable on $B(a,\rho')$. But, since $a$ was arbitrary, it is infinitely often differentiable on whole $G$ --- answering to the claim of the title. How does it sound?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @MartinR Beautiful. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in G$ there is an $R > 0$ such that $B(a, R) \subset G$. Setting $r =R/2$ one has $\overline{B(a,r)}\subset B(a, R) \subset G$. Now one can show with induction that for all integers $n \ge 0$:

- $f$ is $n$-times differentiable in $B(a, r)$, and
- for all $z_0 \in B(a, r)$, $$\tag{*}f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\,dz \, .
  $$

For $n=0$ this is Cauchy's integral formula. For the inductive step you have to show that you can differentiate under the integral sign on the right-hand side of $(*)$.

This shows that $f$ is infinitely often differentiable in a neighbourhood of every $a \in G$, which proves the claim.

So Cauchy's formula for the derivatives shows (for each $n$) both the existence of the $n$-th derivative, and the representation of $f^{(n)}$ as an integral.